# On 4 random points in a rectangle

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, geometric-probability, triangles

> Given a bounded rectangular area, I generate 4 random points. What is the probability that the fourth point lie within a triangle formed the first 3?

How would I attack this problem?  The goal is to eliminate points by knowing whether they are encompassed by any 3 other points.

Comment: Find the expected area of a triangle generated by three random points.

Comment: By affine invariance, it boils down to the case of a square, and the answer in the same in an arbitrary parallelogram.

Comment: This is a topic for MSE.

Comment: What is MSE?  ***

Comment: @Brad The shortcut MSE is here commonly used for the [math.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in [Square Triangle Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html), the mean area of a triangle picked inside a rectangle of unit area is 11/144. So the probability that the fourth point lands inside this triangle is $11/144=0.0764$.

See [Polygon Triangle Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonTrianglePicking.html) for the corresponding probability $p_n$ when the square is replaced by any regular $n$-polygon,
$$p_n=\frac{9\cos^2(2\pi/n)+52\cos(2\pi/n)+44}{36n^2\sin^2(2\pi/n)},$$
a remarkable formula derived by Alikoski in 1939. The $n\rightarrow\infty$ limit gives the probability $35/48\pi^2=0.0739$ for a circle (equal to the average area of a triangle inside a disc of unit area).

Comment: Does the 'circle of unit area' stipulation change the result?  Would it be the same for any circle?

Comment: yes, the probabililty is a dimensionless number, so it does not depend on the area.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker you probably mean regular polygon, not "any polygon". For instance approximating a square with polygons with $\ge 5$ vertices the probability should tend to $11/144$.

Comment: @Brad as I said in another comment, the problem is affinely invariant. Hence the answer is the same for all ellipses.

Comment: @YCor --- indeed, corrected --- thanks.